# How is defined the dual frame of a vector bundle?

Tags: vector-bundles, dual-spaces

In this article [Geometric wave equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706) by Stefan Waldmann he has at page 7

> For a chart $(U, x)$ we consider a compact subset $K \subseteq U$ together with a collection $\left\{e_{\alpha}\right\}_{\alpha=1, \ldots, N}$ of local sections $e_{\alpha} \in \Gamma^{\infty}\left(\left.E\right|_{U}\right)$ such that $\left\{e_{\alpha}(p)\right\}_{\alpha=1, \ldots, N}$ is a basis of the fiber $E_{p}$. We always assume that $U$ is sufficiently small or e.g. contractible such that local base sections exist. The collection $\left\{e_{\alpha}\right\}_{\alpha=1, \ldots, N}$ will also be called a local frame. The dual frame will then be denoted by $\left\{e^{\alpha}\right\}_{\alpha=1, \ldots, N}$ where $e^{\alpha} \in \Gamma^{\infty}\left(\left.E^{*}\right|_{U}\right)$ are the local sections with $e^{\alpha}\left(e_{\beta}\right)=\delta_{\beta}^{\alpha}$. For $s \in \Gamma^{\infty}(E)$ we have unique functions $s^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha}(s) \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(U)$ such that
> $$
> \left.s\right|_{U}=s^{\alpha} e_{\alpha}
> $$

Is $\delta_{\beta}^{\alpha}$ a function or a number? If it is a number how
this operation $e^{\alpha}\left(e_{\beta}\right)$ is defined?

Comment: Is that not a Kronecker $\delta$?

Comment: @Randall I edited my question.

Comment: Right, it is a Kronecker $\delta$.  This is a standard thing used to define dual spaces.  Like here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space

Comment: @Randall I think is a function on the manifold.

Answer (score 0):

For a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $K$ and a basis $(b_\alpha)$, its dual basis $(b^\alpha)$ is defined by the properties

$b^\alpha(b_\alpha)\ =\ 1$
$b^\alpha(b_\beta)\ =\ 0 \ \text{ if } \alpha\ne \beta\,.$

This can be written by a single equation: $b^\alpha(b_\beta)=\delta^\alpha_\beta$ where $\delta^\alpha_\beta$ is the *Kronecker delta*, which is a number, it's $1$ if $\alpha=\beta$ and $0$ if $\alpha\ne\beta$.

Note that the elements of the dual space $V^*$ are linear functionals $V\to K$ and as such they are uniquely determined by their values on a given basis.

Also note that the functional $b^\alpha$ just assigns the $\alpha$th coordinate of any vector $\in V$ when written in the basis $(b_\beta)$.

Comment: Note that $e^{\alpha} \in \Gamma^{\infty}\left(\left.E^{*}\right|_{U}\right)$. So for  example when a one form $dx^\alpha$ acts on a vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}$ it give us a function $\delta^\alpha_\beta$